# Longpress on mapview returns GeoPoint that is below the area that is actually longpressed

Tags: android, android-mapview, long-press, geopoints

It seems that longpress on google mapview returns a GeoPoint below the area that is actually longpressed.

If for example I pressed on (x,y):

Geopoint longpressLocation.getLatitudeE6().getLatitudeE6() = x 
Geopoint longpressLocation.getLatitudeE6().getLongtitudeE6() = y + z
Where z is around 1cm on the map.

Did anyone encountered this before?

Code:

```
 private void setOnLongPress() {
    mMapView.setOnLongpressListener(new LongPressableMapView.OnLongpressListener() {
        public void onLongpress(final MapView view, final GeoPoint longpressLocation) {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() 
            {
                public void run() 
                {
                    // Insert your longpress action here
                    Log.e("lat", String.valueOf(longpressLocation.getLatitudeE6()));
                    Log.e("lng", String.valueOf(longpressLocation.getLongitudeE6()));
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately, google fixed it in Google Map API2